# $\phi$-mixing rate and AR process

Tags: stochastic-processes, mixing

The general definition of the $\phi$-mixing coefficient is as follows:
\begin{equation}
\phi(\sigma_{1},\sigma_{2}) = \underset{B\in\sigma_{1},A\in\sigma_{2}}{\sup} P(A|B)-P(A)
\end{equation}

Then for the process $\{X_{t}\}$, we define:
\begin{equation}
\phi(n) = \phi(\mathcal{F}_{-\infty}^{0}, \mathcal{F}_{n}^{\infty})
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{F}_{-\infty}^{0}$ denotes the sigma algebra generated by $X_{0}, X_{-1},\ldots$ and $\mathcal{F}_{n}^{\infty}$ denotes the sigma algebra generated by $X_{n}, X_{n+1},\ldots$

Now suppose that the process of $X_{t}$ follows a stationary AR(1) process 
\begin{equation}
X_{t} = \rho X_{t-1} + u_{t}
\end{equation}
where $|\rho|<1$, and $u_{t}$ is a white noise with absolutely continuous density.

**My question** : is $X_{t}$ $\phi$-mixing? If so, can we determine the rate of the $\phi$-mixing coefficient? Or the coefficient diminishes at what rate?